# Access and test cookie with blade view

Tags: laravel, cookies

I access the cookie correctly with laravel blade view.
{{ Cookie::get('lg') }} returns the correct language (here, 'en')

But when doing this, I get the french translation... I don't understand how this is possible. Is there anything wrong here? Can't i test it like this/ is the cookies returned later?

```
<h1 class="text-center" style="font-size: 120%">{{ Cookie::get('lg') == 'en' ? 'Reset Password' : Cookie::get('lg')=='fr'?'Modifier le mot de passe' : 'Cambiar contraseña' }}</h1>
```

Comment: Please can you show how you're setting the cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think small bracket is missing over there.

```
<h1 class="text-center" style="font-size: 120%">{{ Cookie::get('lg') == 'en' ? 'Reset Password' : (Cookie::get('lg')=='fr' ? 'Modifier le mot de passe' : 'Cambiar contraseña') }}</h1>
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot, this wasn't very clever :D

Comment: @gertrude Cool ;)